# How to pass argument to constructor

Tags: php

I am trying to pass parameter to my class constructor but cant.

My method

```
public function any(){
    $config=config('myconfig.details');
    $service = MyService::class($config);
    $service = $service->details();

}
```

My class constructor

```
class MyService
{
    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
}
```

Whats my Wong here
I am getting error

```
Call to undefined method MyService::class()
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for creating an object with passing parameters to class constructor is:

```
$service = new MyService($config);
```

> To create a new object, use the `new` statement to instantiate a class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php